# ¿Cómo leo los datos de un xml para mostrarlos en una list box en C#?

Tags: c#, xml

[image: Esto es lo que tengo en el xml:]

Y de código tengo esto:

```
        XmlNodeList xml = lista.GetElementsByTagName("Respuesta");

        foreach (XmlElement res in xml)
        {
           lstCanciones.Items.Add(res.GetAttribute("nombre"));
           lstCanciones.Update();
        }
```

Comment: y cual seria el problema? mira por favor [tour] y [ask]

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu problema, pero tal vez te sirva esta [página del sitio de Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Tu forma de refrescar la lista es ineficiente. Utiliza `BeginUpdate` y `EndUpdate` como en:

```
listBox1.BeginUpdate();
  // Loop through and add 50 items to the ListBox.
  for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
  {
     listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
  }
  // Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
  listBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Yo entiendo que la persona que pregunta necesita saber cómo obtener datos de un fichero XML y listar los datos en un objeto `ListBox`. Intenta mejorar tu respuesta orientándola a esa situación.

Comment: Por el foreach asumí que ya sabe qué tipos de datos está usando y qué esta haciendo con ellos. Dijo que ese código es suyo.

Comment: Te recomiendo que partas del código propuesto por el que realiza la pregunta para mejorarlo con la propuesta que haces.

Comment: Yo recomiendo siempre no contestar la pregunta hasta tanto quien la hizo no aclare cual es el problema. Esto parece mas una ptimizacion que una respuesta de cualquier tipo.

Comment: Si, disculpen por no formular bien la pregunta, ese xml es el que tengo y necesito que la list box muestre los datos, pero no se como acceder a los atributos de cada canción, por ejemplo, obtener el nombre de las canciones o los artistas